# Styling an <li> within another <li>?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<ul id='foo'>
  <li class='fooitem'>
    <ul class='grok'>
      <li class='grokitem'></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to style the fooitem elements differently than the grokitem elements:

```
#foo li {
  background-color: red;
}

.grok li {
  background-color: green;
}
```

but the #foo li definition is overriding the .grok li definition, so all are appearing red. How do I define a style for the grok items?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a slightly different style rule (currently the first, with an ID, has a greater level of specifity).
You can resolve it like this:

```
#foo li {
  background-color: red;
}

#foo .grok li {
  background-color: green;
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/zCWah/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by creating a more specific rule like so:

```
#foo li {
    background-color: red;
}

#foo .grok li {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `li`s appear to have classes assigned to them, you can target them specifically, like so:

```
ul.grok li.grokitem
{
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#foo li {
  background-color: red;
}

#foo .grok li {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any classes in your example

```
#foo li { background-color: red; } // All <li>s in foo

#foo li li { background-color: green; } // All <li>s in <li>s in foo
```